# How to get Number of Imported URLs OWASP ZAP

Tags: security, url, dynamic, zap

I'm doing DAST analysis throught Owasp Zap to differents microservices. In one point, before the crawler ran, they give me this:

> ```
> 2022-07-20 19:26:11,517 Number of Imported URLs: 7
> Total of 93 URLs
> ```

Is there a way to get these two number on a variable? I look in the 3 types of reports (XML, HTM and Json) but I could'nt see these quantities

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ZAP maintains internal statistics which include the number of spiders found by the 2 spiders: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/internal-statistics/ These statistics can be accessed via the ZAP API.

The stats are also available to reports - see https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/report-generation/create/

Some reports like 'traditional-html-plus' include the statistics or you can create your own reports.